# Xcode 5.1: Develop apps for iPad 1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I create a new project, then set the Deployment Target to 5.1.1 (by typing it in). I can run the app in the simulator, but when I run it on my good old iPad with IOS 5.1.1. It displays a black screen and in the console I see

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPad' in bundle NSBundle /var/mobile/Applications/404931A2-E5FD-46D0-88CE-19CEFF459298/singleview.app (loaded)'

Does Xcode 5.1 support my iPad?

Comment: My projects are simple. I did File - New - Project OpenGL Game or Single View Application. That is all.

Comment: do you still need help? did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the iOS project, make sure it is set to `Universal` that one contains a second storyboard called `Main_iPad`.

[image]

Comment: The device is Universal. I have changed nothing  in the settings when creating the projects. It creates two storyboards, runs in the simulator, but not on my devices. Not my ipad and not on my ipod touch

Answer (score 0):

You might see a warning on the side saying something like "Internationalization of /Users/......../Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard is not available when compiling for targets before iOS 6.0"

Switch the localization to just be English (or whatever your specific language is) and uncheck the "Base" one. It'll go through a couple warnings to overwrite the file and set the localization back to the default format.

I had this problem this morning and that fixed it.

[edit]: Right after writing this I also saw a setting called "Use Base Internationalization" in the project settings. Disabling that checkbox will also delete the base and should solve it, I think.